# OS X: Keep commands working in terminal

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, terminal

when I try to use `mysql` or `mysqldump` command in terminal I receive an error saying `mysql: command not found`. Ok the next step is to add the path of mysql: something like this `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/bin`. After that I can use both commands without problem, but if I close the Terminal or restart the computer the mysql/mysqldump command is not recognised by the terminal again. Do you know what could be happening?
I'm using OS X Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below line to `.bash_profile` for the changes to take effect on every new shell on your `OS X` system. Not doing so, leaves the changes only on your current working shell and the changes are lost at the end of the shell exit.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/bin
```

`.bash_profile` is read at start-up of every new session, so that now the shell knows which path it should pick up the `mysql` executable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ive been investigating about ```.bashrc``` file but I cannot find it in my computer. It's in ```home``` folder? because I just can see ```.bash_history``` and ```.bash_sessions``` or should I create it?

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike: Yeah, create one along with the other files you mentioned  with contents as the one I updated above.

Comment: I just did how you said but didn't work but instead I just created a .bash_profile and put in there ```export PATH="/usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/bin:$PATH"``` Thank you for the help. Could you update your answer please. Just followed the paths from this url: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/ :)

Answer (score 0):

On macOS you can always add it to `/etc/paths.d` by creating a file there called something like `90-mysql` with the content:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/bin
```

That will apply to new shells, so you will need to create a new terminal window for that to take effect.

The other option is to create a link in `/usr/bin` to whatever binaries in that directory you want to use. That's more of a hack and probably less elegant than the `paths.d` option.